# How to delete child element in python beatifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want delete google translate's original text.

but couldnt deleted below code, How to do it?

```
soup =  BeautifulSoup(feature1, "lxml")
soup.find("span", {"class":"google-src-text"}).extract()
feature2 = soup.get_text()
```

html code:

```
 <span class="google-src-text" >original</span> == $0  "translated"
```

result:

```
original translated
```

Comment: ddi you look through the docs?
 https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=delete#extract

Comment: Thank you. I tried extract() , the result same.  original text is   <span class="google-src-text" >original</span> == $0  "translated"    (==$0 is something wrong?)

Answer (score 2):

try this with replaceWith functionality

```
soup =  BeautifulSoup(feature1, "lxml")
tag=soup.find("span", {"class":"google-src-text"})
tag.replaceWith('')
feature2 = soup.get_text()
```

you can also use `tag.decompose()` instead of `tag.replaceWith('')`

Comment: I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Since BS4 you have to use [replace_with()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) instead.